# dotnet restore gives a 401, "Unable to load the service index"

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

In a new netcore20 project I am using `dotnet test` for the first time, this restores and builds and its the restore part that's failing.

I'm using Visual Studio Code for the first time.

```
"C:\Data\Git\PDQShockerRestAPI\src\PDQShockerRestAPIWebApp.UnitTests\PDQShockerRestAPIWebApp.UnitTests.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
       (Restore target) ->
         C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\NuGet.targets(102,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://contoso-pdq.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/ContosoPDQNetFramework/nuget/v3/index.json.\r [C:\Data\Git\PDQShockerRestAPI\src\PDQShockerRestAPIWebApp.UnitTests\PDQShockerRestAPIWebApp.UnitTests.csproj]
       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\NuGet.targets(102,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Data\Git\PDQShockerRestAPI\src\PDQShockerRestAPIWebApp.UnitTests\PDQShockerRestAPIWebApp.UnitTests.csproj]
```

I've copied the `.nuget` folder from another solution into `/src/.nuget` in this solution but it doesn't work.

My hunch is that VS2017 was authenticated automatically perhaps via the IDE and that VSCode isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feed is on VSTS. I needed to download and run the NuGet authentication helper tool for VSTS.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/auth-old

After running that tool against my `/src/.nuget/NuGet.config` I was presented with a mini login browser window and signed-in to VSTS. After a few seconds it completed and when I tried `dotnet test` again it was fine.

```
PS C:\Data\Git\PDQShockerRestAPI\src\.nuget> ./VSS.NuGet.AuthHelper.exe -Config .\NuGet.Config
Getting new credentials for source:VSO Libraries Feed, scope:vso.packaging_write vso.drop_write
```

Interestingly, no changes were made to the `NuGet.config` file I specified..!

Comment: 404 on https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/auth-old